# Create an array from Listbox(multiple selections) values in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, listbox

I've seen a lot of question about how to fill a Listbox from an Array in PHP.
What I'm looking for is the complete opposite. I have a listbox in a form and I want the listbox selected options to be stored in a PHP array. Here's my Listbox:

```
<select size=4 multiple class="formfields" id="hardwareinfo" name="hardwareinfo[]">
  <option name="ram" value="ram"> RAM </option>
  <option name="aircard" value="aircard"> Aircard </option>
  <option name="videocard" value="videocard"> Video Card </option>
  <option name="other" value="other"> Other </option>
</select></td>
```

I would like to get the selected values by the user in a PHP array and then store this array in MySQL (I will probably use implode)

As long as somebody can help me creating the array I should be able to figure out the rest :)

Thank you very much

Comment: Check out this page to cycle through the selected objects in the listbox: http://www.mredkj.com/tutorials/tutorial004.html

Then, you can json encode them and send them to the server, where you can run `json_decode` to get an array from it. Hope this helps!

*Edited due to pre-mature posting*

Comment: you just need to send these details via http request. for that you can use form(hopefully you are using that) or jquery. after you have send  the request save the sent value(for exampple $_POST) in array. Hope it is something for you resume trying

Comment: Jeremy unfortunately I want to transfer the values through PHP and store it in an array and then, store this Array in a MySQL field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove name attribute from option tags.

```
<select size=4 multiple class="formfields" id="hardwareinfo" name="hardwareinfo[]">
  <option value="ram"> RAM </option>
  <option value="aircard"> Aircard </option>
  <option value="videocard"> Video Card </option>
  <option value="other"> Other </option>
</select>
```

all you need is to check $_POST['hardwareinfo'] or $_GET['hardwareinfo'], depending on your form type.
you can loop this var by foreach, or simply see contents by var_dump.

Comment: I understand I could make a loop with for each but how to put each value in the same array to store it in a MySQL database afterwards?

Comment: you can use implode() function to do that.